# How to properly include covariates in a one-way repeated measures ANCOVA? What do results tell me?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, ancova

I want to test the effect of a suicide prevention film on help-seeking. I have help-seeking intentions as an outcome variable and measured this variable at three time points (pre, post, follow-up) in 40 participants. To analyse the data I would conduct a one-way repeated measures ANOVA and compare mean differences between the three time points. However, in the pre condition I also assessed depressionscore, indentification with male gender (cses) and identification with the protagonist. Now I would like to consider these variables in the comparison of the means. Since my sample is small and because I did not experimentally manipulate those variables, I don't want to use dichotomized factor variables and conduct a mixed ANOVA. So I would prefer to include the three variables as covariates. However, I have searched a lot of sources, and did not find valid information on wether this can be done. Since usual ANCOVA models are applied in situations with additional treatment factors, which I don't have. So checking for assumptions is based on comparing treatment groups. Moreover I have doubts on what the analysis would tell me?

I used the r `rstatix` package in r and the included functions `anova_test` and `get_anova_table`. Here is the code:

```
res.aov <- anova_test(
  data = data_csv, dv = help_seeking_privat, wid = ID,
  within = time, covariate = c(depressionscore, cses, identification)
)
get_anova_table(res.aov)
```

The results I get are the following:

```
ANOVA Table (type II tests)

                 Effect  DFn   DFd         F     p p<.05      ges
1       depressionscore 1.00 35.00 3.950e-06 0.998       9.36e-08
2                  cses 1.00 35.00 5.470e-01 0.464       1.30e-02
3        identification 1.00 35.00 2.806e+00 0.103       6.20e-02
4                  time 1.56 54.55 4.351e+00 0.026     * 2.10e-02
5  depressionscore:time 1.56 54.55 5.480e-01 0.538       3.00e-03
6             cses:time 1.56 54.55 2.820e-01 0.700       1.00e-03
7   identification:time 1.56 54.55 3.200e-02 0.940       1.56e-04
```

I would conclude that there is a significant effect of time and proceede with pairwise t.tests for post hoc analysis, as I would with a repeated measures ANOVA. Considering the Covariates however, they did not have significant effects. did I include them properly? How do I interpret the results of the covariates? I also ran a repeated measures ANOVA without to covariates and got similar results, however some values differed indicating that the inclusion of these covariates did affect the results. And are there any additional assumptions which I need to check before reporting the results? While checking assumptions, I only checked repeated measures ANOVA assumptions, and the ANCOVA assumption of a linear relation between the covariate and the dependent variable in every time point. Because I did not find any guide on what assumptions must be met in this case, since every guide I found included a between subjects factor and checked assumptions for this factor and not the within subject factor.

I would appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: I think you can include them as covariates. 

Your design would be a lot stronger with a control group, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I totally agree with you, I would have done it, it was rather an issue of resources, since this is my bachelor thesis and I had time and money restrictions. Do you have an idea considering additional assumptions?

Comment: And I am wondering how I would report an interaction effect of covariate and time factor? Would I conduct any kind of Posthoc analysis? An if yes how?  Since I don't have another factor to do mean comparisons? Or would I just state the covariate had an significant effect on the mean comparisons of the time factor and that is enough?

Comment: It looks like you have time as a numeric variable (from the output). That's probably a mistake. The effect is not likely to be linear. 

For interpretation, I think plots would be useful. Some of your parameter estimates seem small, considering your topic. 

I don't THINK there are more assumptions, but I don't usually use RM ANOVA, I use multilevel models.